Azure Storage Account - Reliably waiting for firewall changes in pipeline
We are using Terraform to deploy our infrastructure. As such, we use an Azure Storage Account to host the state files. Obviously, we would much prefer to not have the storage account open to the public network and instead temporarily add the agent's IP address to the firewall rules.
We have the following script that updates the storage account's FW rules and then attempts to pull a blob. As long as it fails, it sleeps and then tries again, maxing out at ~10m threshold.
$attemptCount = 1
$attempInterval = 5
$maxAttempts = ((60 * 10) + $attempInterval) / $attempInterval # Try for 10 mins

# Traditional try/catch does not work in ADO pipelines for whatever reason
# Retry logic below was created using this as ref: https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2019/07/12/Azure-CLI-PowerShell

while ($true)
{
    if ($attemptCount -gt $maxAttempts)
    {
        Write-Host "Maximum attempts made on firewall rule / access. Aborting script."
        return 1
    }

    Write-Host "Trying storage account firewall (attempt $attemptCount of $maxAttempts)"

    $output = az storage blob exists --account-key $key --account-name $storageAccountName --container-name "tfstate" --name someBlob | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Debug "Last exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Storage account access failed; sleeping"
        $attemptCount = $attemptCount + 1
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $attempInterval
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Successfully connected to service account"
        break
    }
}

This seems to work sometimes:
<Storage account logs>
Trying storage account firewall (attempt 1 of 121)
ERROR: 
The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account. Please check network rule set using 'az storage account show -n accountname --query networkRuleSet'.
If you want to change the default action to apply when no rule matches, please use 'az storage account update'.
                    
Storage account access failed; sleeping
Trying storage account firewall (attempt 2 of 121)
Successfully connected to service account

<Terraform init logs>
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

And other times, it doesn't:
<Storage account logs>
Trying storage account firewall (attempt 1 of 121)
ERROR: 
The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account. Please check network rule set using 'az storage account show -n accountname --query networkRuleSet'.
If you want to change the default action to apply when no rule matches, please use 'az storage account update'.
                    
Storage account access failed; sleeping
Trying storage account firewall (attempt 2 of 121)
Successfully connected to service account

<Terraform init logs>
Initializing the backend...
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\nTime:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


Mind you, this is all run on the same agent in the same stage and same job, so my question is: why does the agent seem to "lose" access a couple steps later when Terraform runs?
Update 1
I updated my PowerShell to create a file rather than just checking existence, wondering if there's a layering effect that maybe I can check for a file, but can't actually read/write.
$output = az storage blob upload -f $testFilePath --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $key --container-name "tfstate" -n connTest --overwrite | ConvertFrom-Json

This also exhibits the behavior where it will push the file up, but Terraform's init errors.
Update 2
I am also finding that my cleanup of the test file will also fail sometimes, meaning that between pushing the file and then trying to delete the file within the same script, something messes up.
Trying storage account firewall (attempt 2 of 121)

<File is uploaded here>
Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
Successfully connected to service account

<File fails to be deleted here>
ERROR: 
The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account. Please check network rule set using 'az storage account show -n accountname --query networkRuleSet'.
If you want to change the default action to apply when no rule matches, please use 'az storage account update'.

Update 3
Here is the job YAML. It's somewhat abstracted so it is reusable across deploy and destroy operations.
parameters:
  - name: jobName
    type: string

  - name: displayName
    type: string

  - name: planOnly
    type: boolean

  - name: destroy
    type: boolean

  - name: env
    type: string

  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string

  - name: subscriptionId
    type: string

  - name: terraformBackendName
    type: string

  - name: terraformBackendResourceGroup
    type: string

  - name: workingDirectory
    type: string

  - name: dependsOn
    type: object
    default: []

  - name: condition
    type: object
    default: null

  - name: preTerraformSteps
    type: stepList
    default: []

  - name: postTerraformSteps
    type: stepList
    default: []

jobs:
  - job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
    displayName: ${{ parameters.displayName }}
    container: toolkit
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
    condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}

    variables:
      ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, true) }}:
        destroyString: "-destroy"
      ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, false) }}:
        destroyString: ""

    steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: Store service principal
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          useGlobalConfig: true
          inlineScript: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Arm.Client.Id;issecret=true]${servicePrincipalId}"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Arm.Client.Secret;issecret=true]${servicePrincipalKey}"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Arm.Tenant.Id;issecret=true]${tenantId}"

              Current_IP=$(curl -s ipinfo.io/ip)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Agent.IP;issecret=false]$Current_IP"
          failOnStandardError: true

      - checkout: self
      - checkout: terraform-modules

      - template: steps/modify_sa_fw.yml
        parameters:
          serviceConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
          subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
          resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.terraformBackendResourceGroup }}
          storageAccountName: ${{ parameters.terraformBackendName }}
          ipAddress: $(Agent.IP)
          open: true

      - script: "git config --global http.extraHeader 'Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)'"
        displayName: Persist Git credentials
        failOnStderr: true

      - script: |
          cd ./terraform-build-agents-master-mold
          cp ./infrastructure/common/*.tf ./${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
        displayName: 'Copy common files'

      - ${{ if ne(length(parameters.preTerraformSteps), 0) }}:
        - ${{ parameters.preTerraformSteps }}

      - script: |
          cd ./terraform-build-agents-master-mold/${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
          terraform init \
            -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.terraformBackendResourceGroup }}" \
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.terraformBackendName }}" \
            -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}" \
            -backend-config="container_name=tfstate" \
            -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.jobName }}/terraform.tfstate"
        displayName: 'Terraform Init'
        env:
          TF_INPUT: 0
          TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(Arm.Client.Id)
          ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(Arm.Client.Secret)
          ARM_TENANT_ID: $(Arm.Tenant.Id)
          ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ parameters.subscriptionID }}
          AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL: $(System.CollectionUri)

      - script: |
          cd ./terraform-build-agents-master-mold/${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
          terraform plan ${{ variables.destroyString }} -out=tfplan \
            -var-file="../../envs/${{ parameters.env }}/terraform.tfvars" \
            -var-file="../common/terraform.tfvars" \
            -var="backend_resource_group_name=${{ parameters.terraformBackendResourceGroup }}" \
            -var="backend_storage_account_name=${{ parameters.terraformBackendName }}"
        displayName: "Terraform Plan"
        env:
          TF_INPUT: 0
          TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(Arm.Client.Id)
          ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(Arm.Client.Secret)
          ARM_TENANT_ID: $(Arm.Tenant.Id)
          ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ parameters.subscriptionID }}
          AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL: $(System.CollectionUri)
          AGENT_IP: $(Agent.IP)

      - ${{ if eq(parameters.planOnly, false) }}:
        - script: |
            cd ./terraform-build-agents-master-mold/${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
            terraform apply ${{ variables.destroyString }} tfplan
          displayName: "Terraform Apply"
          env:
            TF_INPUT: 0
            TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
            SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
            ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(Arm.Client.Id)
            ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(Arm.Client.Secret)
            ARM_TENANT_ID: $(Arm.Tenant.Id)
            ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ parameters.subscriptionID }}
            AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
            AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL: $(System.CollectionUri)
            AGENT_IP: $(Agent.IP)

      - ${{ if ne(length(parameters.postTerraformSteps), 0) }}:
        - ${{ parameters.postTerraformSteps }}

      - template: steps/modify_sa_fw.yml
        parameters:
          serviceConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
          subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
          resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.terraformBackendResourceGroup }}
          storageAccountName: ${{ parameters.terraformBackendName }}
          ipAddress: $(Agent.IP)
          open: false

The step steps/modify_sa_fw.yml invokes this yml:
parameters:
  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string

  - name: subscriptionId
    type: string

  - name: resourceGroupName
    type: string

  - name: storageAccountName
    type: string

  - name: ipAddress
    type: string

  - name: open
    type: boolean

steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    ${{ if eq(parameters.open, true) }}:
      displayName: Open storage account firewall
    ${{ if eq(parameters.open, false) }}:
      displayName: Close storage account firewall
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      scriptPath: terraform-build-agents-master-mold/scripts/modify_sa_fw.ps1
      arguments: '-subscriptionId ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }} -resourceGroupName ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} -storageAccountName ${{ parameters.storageAccountName }} -ip "${{ parameters.ipAddress }}" -add ${{ parameters.open }}'
      failOnStandardError: false

Which invokes this Powershell script:
param ($subscriptionId,$resourceGroupName,$storageAccountName,$ip,$add)

#region functions
function Exec-WithRetry
{
    param(
        $attemptIntervalInSeconds,
        $maxRetryTimeInSeconds,
        $action
    )

    $attemptCount = 1
    $maxAttempts = $maxRetryTimeInSeconds / $attemptIntervalInSeconds

    while ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts)
    {
        Write-Host "Trying attempt $attemptCount of $maxAttempts"

        $output = $action.Invoke
        Write-Debug "Last exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0)
        {
            Write-Host "Attempt failed; sleeping"
            $attemptCount = $attemptCount + 1
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $attemptIntervalInSeconds
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Attempt succeeded"
            return 0
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Maxium retries reached; aborting"
    return 1
}

function Add-FirewallException
{
    param(
        $key
    )

    Write-Host "Adding $ip to storage account firewall rules"
    az storage account network-rule add -g $resourceGroupName -n $storageAccountName --ip-address $ip

    # create a file to test uploading
    Write-Debug "Creating local test file to test storage account firewall"
    $testFilePath = "./sa-test.txt"
    New-Item $testFilePath -ItemType File -Value "xyz"

    return Exec-WithRetry -attemptIntervalInSeconds 10 `
        -maxRetryTimeInSeconds (10*60) `
        -action {
            return az storage blob upload -f $testFilePath --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $key --container-name "tfstate" -n connTest --overwrite | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
}

function Remove-FirewallException
{
    param(
        $key
    )

    Write-Host "Removing $ip from storage account firewall rules"

    return Exec-WithRetry -attemptIntervalInSeconds 5 `
        -maxRetryTimeInSeconds (5*60) `
        -action {
            return az storage account network-rule remove -g $resourceGroupName -n $storageAccountName --ip-address $ip | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
}

function Get-AccessKey
{
    # See if network rule took
    $keys_resp = az storage account keys list -g $resourceGroupName -n $storageAccountName | Out-String
    $keys_json = ConvertFrom-Json $keys_resp
    return $keys_json[0].value
}
#endregion

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

Write-Debug "Getting access key"
$key = Get-AccessKey

if ($add -eq $true)
{
    return Add-FirewallException $key
}
else
{
    return Remove-FirewallException $key
}


Hello Matt,
were you able to find a better solution? We have exactly the same problem. We have a terraform pipeline running on MS hosted agents that is used to setup self-hosted Agents for later stages of our Landingzone.
We also wait for the network rule to be propagated by trying to access the storage in a loop, but sometimes we still get "The request may be blocked by network rules of storage account" after our wait script succeeded.

Update
Based on the further discussions and updates, I can totally understand your requirement to leverage the benefits of MS-hosted agents; however, please note that we are not guaranteed to be assigned with the same agent machine as you mentioned in the post during each pipeline run. The MS-hosted agents considered as Standard_DS2_v2 Azure VM resources can also be affected by the Azure storage limitation shared in the previous answer below. Therefore, the pipeline workflow to access your Azure Storage Account running on a MS-hosted agent is sure to be unreliable.
Per the finding you observed that even your AzureCLI script succeeded to visit your storage account in EastUS from WestUS agent, while your terraform init command still failed to access the same storage account, I wonder if there is a chance that the two tasks were authenticating against different service principals respectively with the one in ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }} and that of $(Arm.Client.Id). For this, you may double check your ADD Sign-in logs to see what could have caused the 403 error, rather than the firewall rules but other settings like Conditional Access Policies, when the underlying service principal of the pipeline task was trying to access the .tfstare file in your storage account.
With those being said, I would highly suggest you use VMSS agent pools, which, as self-hosted agent pools, can be setup in your whitelist VNet(s), and which, as another benefit, can scale in or out based on your incoming agent jobs.

Assuming the agent you mentioned in the description this is all run on the same agent in the same stage and same job, was an Azure VM that was created in the same region as that of the Azure Storage Account resource and configured as a self-hosted pipeline agent, the intermittent failure to access Azure Storage Account from the VM IP could be related to the cases where we can't use IP network rules as introduced in this document.

You can't use IP network rules in the following cases:
To restrict access to clients in same Azure region as the storage account. IP network rules have no effect on requests that originate from the same Azure region as the storage account. Use Virtual network rules to allow same-region requests.
To restrict access to clients in a paired region that are in a virtual network that has a service endpoint.
To restrict access to Azure services deployed in the same region as the storage account. Services deployed in the same region as the storage account use private Azure IP addresses for communication. So, you can't restrict access to specific Azure services based on their public outbound IP address range.

Instead of adding IP ranges to the storage account allow list, we can use Virtual network rules to allow same-region request, which will only check whether the requests are sent from the expected VNet and its subnet, no matter they are sent via public or private IPs.
If by any chance your pipeline was running on a Microsoft-hosted agent, please consider setting up self-hosted agents in the allowlist of the VNet rules.

Thanks for replying, Alvin. However, that doesn't explain the situations where the FW exception seems to take and when TF goes to init, it fails. For instance, all my infra is in East US and I got an agent with IP 13.91.16.87. According to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519, that is a westus agent. Yet, even though I was able to upload my test file, Terraform init fails 5s later because it doesn't have access.

According to your description that  this is all run on the same agent in the same stage and same job, may I assume your pipeline was running on an Azure VM self-hosted agent with the static public IP of 13.91.16.87?

Can you please also share your pipeline YAML definition including the job with the Azure CLI PowerShell script and let us know whether you run the terraform init command in the same Azure CLI task or any other script or extension task? Thx.

This pipeline is being run on a MSFT hosted agent. Its purpose is to bootstrap self-hosted agents so using self-hosted agents for this is nothing something we are looking to do. I will update the post with the pipeline YAML

Hi there, Appreciate your efforts and taking time to share the update.. I have updated the answer with another option for your evaluation. Thx a lot and cheers!
